# regex in php with negative lookbehind

Tags: php, regex

I'm doing some SEO of huge catalog product descriptions using preg_replace_callback and have some difficulties with regex.

I'd like to replace all these words (hat, shirt) except ones after "men's" + 0-2 words between, e.g. "men's pretty black hat", "men's long shirt" shouldn't be replaced.

Here is a debug code, in real application I use callback to pick proper replacement for each word:

```
$str = "men's black hat, and orange shirt!";
preg_match_all('/((\s|\.\s|,\s|\!\s|\?\s)(hat|shirt)(\s|\.|\.\s|,\s|\!|\!\s|\?|\?\s))/i', $str, &$_matches);
print_r($_matches);
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You talked about replacing but are using `preg_match_all`. Also, what is the outcome you are expecting from the debug code you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookbehind must be of fixed length, so this way of attacking the problem won't work.

IMHO you are trying to make `preg_relace_callback` do way too much. If you want to perform manipulation that is complex beyond a certain level, it's reasonable to forfeit the convenience of a single function call. Here's another way you can attack the problem:

1. Use `preg_split` to split the text into words along with the flag `PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE` so that you know where each word appears in the original text.
2. Iterate over the array of words. It's now very easy to do a "negative lookbehind" on the array and see if a hat or shirt is preceded by any one of the other terms that interest you.
3. Whenever you find a positive match for hat or shirt, use the offset from `preg_split` and the (known) length of the positive match to power [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) on the original text input.

For example:

```
$str = "men's black hat, and orange shirt!";
$targets = array('hat', 'shirt');
$shield = 'men\'s';
$bias = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); ++$i) {
    list ($word, $offset) = $words[$i];

    if (!in_array($word, $targets)) {
        continue;
    }

    for ($j = max($i - 2, 0); $j < $i; ++$j) {
        if ($words[$j][0] === $shield) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $replacement = 'FOO';
    $str = substr_replace($str, $replacement, $offset + $bias, strlen($word));
    $bias += strlen($replacement) - strlen($word);
}

echo $str;
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Q2OCya)**.

Comment: Thank you, very good point about preg_split() and further processing. It just works. Thanks, man!

Comment: The only thing is that if replacement "FOO" is not the same length as original `$word` then `$offset` is incorrect after first iteration => substr_replace will mess original text :) I solved it with `$offsetCorrection += (strlen($replacement) - strlen($word))`

Comment: @c0rewell: Yup, that's definitely a bug and I really should have caught it. Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think variable-length negative lookbehinds are possible.

A trick is to reverse the string and use negative lookaheads. So, where you'd "ideally" want to do:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\bmen\'s\s+(\w+\s+){0,2})(hat|shirt)\b/i', $str, &$_matches);
```

you could do

```
preg_match_all('/\b(tah|trihs)(?!(\s+\w+){0,2}\s+s\'nem\b)/i', strrev($str), $rev_matches);
```

and then use `array_map` to reverse all the results back.

By the way, `\b` is known as a *word boundary*. They're probably what you mean to use instead of all the `(\s|\.|\.\s|,\s|\!|\!\s|\?|\?\s)`.

Comment: Another way to emulate a variable-length lookbehind is to use `\K`. Anything matched prior to encountering `\K` is discarded/"forgotten", which effectively allows you to match anything then only start capturing after `\K`. Search for "Resetting the match start" about halfway down the [PCRE manpages](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Comment: No problem. I like \@Jon's solution better, myself, and didn't know about @Wiseguy's `\K` construct either.